# Formatting dataframe to rows based on keys in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame like one below:

```
tag_id      value      time_stamp
tag_1      1          2017-05-01 00:00:00
tag_2      2          2017-05-01 00:00:00
tag_3      3          2017-05-01 00:00:00
tag_1      4          2017-05-01 00:10:00
tag_2      5          2017-05-01 00:10:00
tag_3      6          2017-05-01 00:10:00
```

I want to format it as under, can someone please help?

```
time_stamp           tag_1     tag_2   tag_3          
2017-05-01 00:00:00  1         2       3
2017-05-01 00:10:00  4         5       6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of pivot.

Assuming `df` is your dataframe.

```
df.pivot(index='time_stamp', values='value', columns='tag_id')
```